# Dim appVisio As Visio.Application in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visio

I am updating a very old VB program that accesses **Visio**.

Using Visual Studio 2017 the statement:

```
Dim appVisio As Visio.Application
```

gives a compile error:

> Type 'Visio.Application' is not defined.

I assume I need to create a reference to something to define this, but I don't see any obvious option in the available references.

Or perhaps I'm way off base and need something else entirely?

Anybody have any thoughts?

Thanks Daniel/Gustav for fixing post and Ken for suggestion.

Clarifying and adding emerging details.

What I am attempting to do is create an .exe that calls Visio.
I did this many years ago and now am now attempting to update using Visual Studio 2017.

In Visual Studio I:

- File, New Project, Installed, Visual Basic, Windows Classic, Desktop, Console App.
- Project, Add Reference..., Microsoft Visio 16.0 Type Library

Visual Studio acts like it accepts the reference, but if I go back and check, it really didn't take.

So the Dim creates the compile error.

So it seems like the underlying problem is Visual Studio not accepting the reference.

Answer (score 3):

You would need a reference to the Viso primary interop assembly

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Working with MS support here's where I ended up:

1. Project, Add Reference...: Assemblies, Extensions: 
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio 15.0.0.0
2. Project, Add Reference...: COM, Type Libraries: Microsoft Visio 16.0 Type Library 4.16 (Note that in my environment this reference appears not to stay selected when coming back into references to check, but it really is selected)
3. In code, before Module line add: Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

With these additions things work for me -- Dim appVisio as Visio.Application compiles and app runs.